# R language's esoph data set, handling ncases and ncontrols with cbind

Tags: r, cbind

The esoph data set in R includes two fields called ncontrols and ncases which are the number of people in the group and the number of people in that group diagnosed with esophogeal cancer.  This statement from the Examples section creates a linear model:

```
model1 <- glm(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ agegp + tobgp*alcgp, 
              data=esoph, family=binomial())
```

My question is on the `cbind` sequence.  Does it magically create auxiliary arrays with zero (no) and one (yes) according to the values of ncases and ncontrols?

Comment: We don't do magic in statistics

Comment: it just sticks the two vectors together to form a matrix (special array). Guess I should have looked at the data before commenting

Answer (score 2):

It *"column binds"* `ncases` and `ncontrols` into a 2-columns matrix as below:

```
> head(esoph)
  agegp     alcgp    tobgp ncases ncontrols
1 25-34 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      0        40
2 25-34 0-39g/day    10-19      0        10
3 25-34 0-39g/day    20-29      0         6
4 25-34 0-39g/day      30+      0         5
5 25-34     40-79 0-9g/day      0        27
6 25-34     40-79    10-19      0         7

> head(cbind(esoph$ncases, esoph$ncontrols))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   40
[2,]    0   10
[3,]    0    6
[4,]    0    5
[5,]    0   27
[6,]    0    7
```

This lets the model know how many cases were positive out of how many trials, i.e. what is the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the two responders above.  Additional information is actually in the glm documentation where the Details section for the first parameter includes possible specification "as a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures".  So it was glm doing the work I was curious about and not cbind.